# XNA, spawning missile

Tags: c#, xna

I have a problem with XNA Game Studio. I have no idea why this code isn't working, how to spawn a missile? What I try to do here is to spawn a missile everytime space is pressed.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();
    keys = Keyboard.GetState();
    if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
    {
        spaceshipRectangle.Y -= 5;
    }
    if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
    {
        spaceshipRectangle.Y += 5;
    }
    if(keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
    {
        missileShot = true;
        missile = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Missile");
        missileRectangle = new Rectangle(spaceshipRectangle.X, spaceshipRectangle.Y, 30, 40);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(missile, missileRectangle, Color.Green);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
    if (missileShot = true)
    {
        missileRectangle.X += 5;
    }
    // TODO: Add your update logic here
    enemyRectangle.X -= 5;
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my memory, XNA has a `Draw()` method or something like that which is seperate from `Update()`? And you put all of your drawing in that method.

**EDIT:** try this:

```
 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
 {
     spriteBatch.Begin();
     //draw all your stuff
     spriteBatch.End();
}
```

Comment: This is the issue, the 3 lines with spriteBatch have to be moved in the Draw method.

Comment: Oh thank you! It's my first game in XNA and had problem with it, I didn't know how Draw void exactly works.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing going wrong here is that you keep overwriting `missile` and `missileRectangle` each time space is pressed, rather than adding a new missile - it looks like you need a list of missiles. Another problem is that you're interspersing your input-processing code, update code and drawing code - what you want is to process your input, add new missiles to a list as appropriate and then loop over the list in (a) your update code, to move them, and (b) your rendering code, to draw them.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't load stuff out of the Load() method.
Load the textures in the Load() method.

try moving this line to the Load() method.

```
missile = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Missile");
```

Also separate your Update and Draw code.